# WPF Setting width of specific column in DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a database application in which I display table with 5 columns in `DataGrid`.

I'm using `XAML` to create UI, and I have problem with setting the width of each `column`.

I know I can use Propetries `ColumnWidth` in `DataGrid` but it sets width of all `columns`.

How can I set the width for every single `column` SEPARATELY?

Answer (score 1):

When you specify your own column layout then each `DataGridColumn` has a `Width` property. If you auto-generate column layout (`AutoGenerateColumns=true`) then `DataGrid` supports a `DataGrid.AutoGeneratingColumn` event which gives you `DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs` data and you can access new column from there and set `Width`, do other changes or cancel column creation altogether. [DataGrid.AutoGeneratingColumn Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.autogeneratingcolumn%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `DataGrid.Columns` Property to define each column manually. Then you can define the `Width` property for each column seperatly.

Refer to this article for examples:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.columns.aspx